# Eleventy programmatic API - what should the input path look like?

Tags: node.js, eleventy

I have a aws lambda function which calls the eleventy.write() or eleventy.toJSON() method but can't seem to make it work. I have tried different project structures and setting different paths but it either returns an empty array or it throws the following error
`TemplateLayoutPathResolver directory does not exist for filename.njk: _includes`
When I run the `eleventy` command from terminal, it builds successfully.
This is my 11ty project structure

```
project root folder
-- public (output of the eleventy build)
-- .eleventy.js
-- src (input for the eleventy build)
  |-- _data
  |-- _includes
```

my .eleventy.js file looks like this:

```
...
 return {
        dir:{
            input: 'src',
            output: 'public',
        },
    };
```

On the lambda function project, where the `write()` call is made, I have tried setting the input path relative to the file, then I tried putting the 11ty root folder next to the .js file and instantiating eleventy like `let eleventy = new Eleventy(".", "public")` which didn't worked and I also tried taking the content of the eleventy root project and placing it next to the .js file I am making the `write()` call.

Also tried setting the configPath like so

```
let eleventy = new Eleventy(".", "public", {
    configPath: "./.eleventy.js",
  });
```

but still not working.

The documentation for the eleventy programmatic API (https://www.11ty.dev/docs/programmatic/) is pretty thin, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your list of files above, in src, I see `includes`, not `_includes`. Did you forget the underscore?

Comment: Forgot to write in in the post, my bad. I updated the post

Comment: And I assume you have files in src? After you fixed the _ issue, what do you get currently? You maybe need to edit the question to reflect the current status/result.

Comment: Yes I do have files in src, and I also had the underscore in _includes initially, it was just a typo in the post, but like I already mentioned, if I build the app using the "eleventy" command, it works just fine. The problem is with the programmatic api

Answer (score 0):

Just set your input folder to "src"

```
let eleventy = new Eleventy("src", "public");
```